# IPhone Configuration : is it possible to configure APN programmatically?

Tags: iphone, configuration, apn

in my iPhone app, I would like to switch from an APN (Access Point Name) to another without using a configuration profile. Does Apple allow a dynamic change of APN ?

Do you have any idea ?

Regards

Comment: Yes its really a nice question, 


Alternative you can register multiple devices for APN 
For registering multiple devices (device id) , then you have to request the device id from the users for which they want the APN

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665356/how-to-change-iphone-apn-access-point-name-programmatically/2665373#2665373) it seems this cannot be done.