# How to change iPhone APN (Access Point Name) programmatically?

Tags: iphone, apn

How to change iPhone APN (Access Point Name) programmatically?

Or force a 3G/GPRS connection to use certain APN programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done with the SDK. Third-party apps don't get that level of control over the hardware, especially not the cell modem.

Answer (score 2):

browse to unlockit.co.nz from your phone. it can change the apn to any predetermined or custom APN on any unlocked iphone